# Alternative to ValidateRequest="false"

Tags: asp.net, http-post, validate-request

Is there a way to prevent the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" other than setting `ValidateRequest="false"`?

**Update:** I removed the "on the page" part. I'd like to not use `ValidateRequest="false"` at all, on the page or in web.config.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the new [ASP.NET 4.5 request validation features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you set

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" ... />
```

in your web.config, values will only get validated when you access them. This is called *deferred validation*.

Also you can get unvalidated values via

```
var s = context.Request.Unvalidated.Form["forum_post"];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm stuck on 4.0 right now, but this is good information.

Answer (score 1):

1 You can also add javascript validation on your input

2 You can Add Custom Validator

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it globally in the web.config.

If you're running .net 4.0 you can add this into your web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Or you could add this instead

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it for the entire application by editing the web.config file

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It would help to know if you want to just suppress the error, or if you want to prevent it from being raised to start with. If you want to prevent it, sanitize your input (using javascript or validators) before submitting the form.